# How to generate a text file with a set number of integers?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, integer

### **TL;DR: The sorting homework I'm working on in Java wants me to use input text files with at least 500,000 integers each. How would I create said files?**

I'm working on some Advanced Java homework right now, and the objective of said homework is to take two inputs from the user: the names of two files with unsorted integers, formatted as:

*10*

*1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15*

where the top number is used to create an array of its size, and the bottom numbers are integers that must be sorted within that array (if there are more integers than the size of the array, the extra ones are ignored).

These input files are then sorted and merged before prompting the user for a file name. The program will take that file name, create a file with it, and dumped the merged integers into that file.

All of this seems doable, but my problem is the final requirement of the homework:

> "**Deliverables:** A screen shot of your program in action, using input files of your own making, but each with a
> size of at least 500,000 integers."

I'm not sure how to go about this. It would be unbelievably tedious if not practically impossible to make by hand, and I don't know of any methods to make the process feasible. Could someone help understand how to create such a file?

Comment: [How to create and write to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2885224/2478398).  [How to create a stream of random integers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48193564/2478398).  Combine these two parts and you have your files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use java.util.Random class and create a stream of integer of the desired size (500k in your case) ranging from a lower bound to an upper one. For example with:

```
new Random().ints(500000,1,12345);
```

you will generate 500k integer between 1 and 12344.
You might save this stream in a string buffer and than write it to a file.